# hash like object in octave

Tags: matlab, octave

I have some built in function in octave as

```
function [val_a,val_b,params] = func_a(X,Y,alpha,params);
age = params.age
height = params.height
```

Here it seems the argument params of func_a contains multiple objects age, height. In general, params should be hash like

```
params = {"age" : 10, "height" : 30}
```

But it gives error in octave. How can I use it in octave or in matlab ?

Comment: Did you try using valid syntax?

Comment: yes, I tried in the same way. When I initialize as `params = {"age" : 10, "height" : 30}`. And try to access `params.age`, it gives error as `error: cell cannot be indexed with .`. I am newbie to octave or matlab. So please help me.

Comment: As I implied **that is not valid syntax**. You need to use a `struct`

Comment: Note: This is **not** a hash (or even a "hash like object").

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all the commenter. I fount it is more like struct, but not hash or hash type object. Here is the solution:

```
field1 = 'age'
value1 = 10
field2 = 'height'
value2 = 30
params = struct(field1, value1, field2, value2)
```

Then we can access as `params.age` and `params.height`.